# Alter the user registration form

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to change the label and field instructions for the name field on the User Account Creation form. I'm new to coding, and thought this would be an easy task.

My custom module is enabled and I've cleared caches, but none of my changes show up. Here is my code. I've tried a bunch of variations and a bunch of searching, but I never see a single sign of this working.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains mymodule.module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() on behalf of mymodule.module.
 * @see \Array method Array at Array
 */
function mymodule_form_account_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // print_r($form); die;
  // ksm($form_id);
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    // print_r($form); die;
    // kint($form_id);
    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('First and last name'),
      '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
      '#description' => $this->t("Rewrite this about spaces, periods (.), hyphens (-) and apostrophes (')."),
    );
  }
  drupal_set_message('mymodule_form_account_alter() executed.');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the right code.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('First and last name');
  $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t("Rewrite this about spaces, periods (.), hyphens (-) and apostrophes (').");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you aren't seeing any change in the user registration form is that the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementation for the *user_register_form* form has the wrong name: Instead of `mymodule_form_account_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)` (which supposes it is defined from a module whose machine name is *mymodule*), it should be `mymodule_form_user_registration_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)`. Alternatively, you could implement `hook_form_alter()` with the `mymodule_form_alter()` function. In this case, checking the form ID would be correct, as the hook would be invoked for each form used by Drupal.

Fixed the hook name, there are still errors in the code you are showing.

1. Inside a function `$this` doesn't have any value/meaning. Only a class method that isn't static can use `$this`.
2. A line like `if ($form_id == 'user_register_form')` is not necessary for `mymodule_form_user_registration_form_alter()`, since that hook is invoked for that form, and not any form a Drupal module is using.
3. If you need to change some of the properties of a form element, you don't use `$form['name'] = array( /* .... */);` which is removing all the properties of that form element and adding **only** the ones you add to the array.
4. The form field for the username, used in the account registration form, is `$form['account']['name']`, not `$form['name']`.

The correct code would be similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['name']['#title'] = new TranslatableMarkup('First and last name');
  $form['account']['name']['#description'] = new TranslatableMarkup("Rewrite this about spaces, periods (.), hyphens (-) and apostrophes (').");
}
```

Notice that:

- While `$form_id` is one of the parameters passed to the hook, you don't need it to understand for which form the hook is invoked. Actually, I cannot think of any reason for `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to use that parameter, except in the case the form ID must be concatenated to another string. (In that case, I would use `$form_id . 'another string'`.) This means the last hook parameter can also be omitted, since the code isn't using it.

  ```php
  function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = new TranslatableMarkup('First and last name');
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = new TranslatableMarkup("Rewrite this about spaces, periods (.), hyphens (-) and apostrophes (').");
  }
  ```
- I used the [`TranslatableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8.9.x) class to output a translated string, which is Drupal 8 suggested class to use in this case, but you could use [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/9.1.x) which is a function Drupal 9 still implements.
- If you are testing when a hook is invoked, don't use `drupal_set_message()` (which is also a deprecated function). Use the Drupal logger, for example with a line like `\Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('mymodule_form_account_alter() executed.');`.

Comment: thanks! the explanation is helpful. it seems the code is missing critical bits, but I greatly appreciate the thoughtful writeup. Between your answer and that of @Kladrian, I have a lot more clarity about hook_form_alter than before.